# R - Group by variable and then assign a unique ID

Tags: r, dplyr

I am interested in de-identifying a sensitive data set with both time-fixed and time-variant values.  I want to (a) group all cases by social security number, (b) assign those cases a unique ID and then (c) remove the social security number.

Here's an example data set:

```
personal_id    gender  temperature
111-11-1111      M        99.6
999-999-999      F        98.2
111-11-1111      M        97.8
999-999-999      F        98.3
888-88-8888      F        99.0
111-11-1111      M        98.9
```

Any solutions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe a lazy solution, but I suppose you could just hash the social security numbers.

Comment: One method would be `set.seed(1234); levels(personal_id) <- sample(length(levels(personal_id)))` Here, the seed would provide a "decryption" key, so you'd want to either hide that or not save it.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`dplyr` has a `group_indices` function for creating unique group IDs

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data.frame(personal_id = c("111-111-111", "999-999-999", "222-222-222", "111-111-111"),
                       gender = c("M", "F", "M", "M"),
                       temperature = c(99.6, 98.2, 97.8, 95.5))

data$group_id <- data %>% group_indices(personal_id) 
data <- data %>% select(-personal_id)

data
  gender temperature group_id
1      M        99.6        1
2      F        98.2        3
3      M        97.8        2
4      M        95.5        1
```

Or within the same pipeline (https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2160):

```
data %>% 
    mutate(group_id = group_indices(., personal_id))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `group_indices()` appears to automatically sort personal_id before creating the group_id, which is not always desired.

Comment: `group_indices()` was deprecated in dplyr 1.0.0.
Please use `cur_group_id()` instead now.

Answer (score 84):

`dplyr::group_indices()` is deprecated as of `dplyr 1.0.0`. `dplyr::cur_group_id()` should be used instead:

```
df %>%
 group_by(personal_id) %>%
 mutate(group_id = cur_group_id())

  personal_id gender temperature group_id
  <chr>       <chr>        <dbl>    <int>
1 111-11-1111 M             99.6        1
2 999-999-999 F             98.2        3
3 111-11-1111 M             97.8        1
4 999-999-999 F             98.3        3
5 888-88-8888 F             99          2
6 111-11-1111 M             98.9        1
```

Comment: This should be the new accepted answer!

Answer (score 2):

Using dplyr package :

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data.frame(personal_id = c("111-111-111", "999-999-999", "222-222-222", "111-111-111"),
                 gender = c("M", "F", "M", "M"),
                 temperature = c(99.6, 98.2, 97.8, 95.5))
```

first you extract the personal_id in order to create a unique ID :

```
cases <- data.frame(levels = levels(data$personal_id))
```

using rownames, you get a unique identifier :

```
cases <- cases %>%
    mutate(id = rownames(cases))
```

results :

```
       levels id
1 111-111-111  1
2 222-222-222  2
3 999-999-999  3
```

then you join the cases dataframe with your data :

```
data <- left_join(data, cases, by = c("personal_id" = "levels"))
```

you create a more unique ID by pasting the id generated with the gender :

```
mutate(UID = paste(id, gender, sep=""))
```

and finally remove the personal_id and the simple id :

```
select(-personal_id, -id)
```

and there you go :) :

```
data <- left_join(data, cases, by = c("personal_id" = "levels")) %>%
        mutate(UID = paste(id, gender, sep="")) %>%
        select(-personal_id, -id)
```

results :

```
  gender temperature UID
1      M        99.6  1M
2      F        98.2  3F
3      M        97.8  2M
4      M        95.5  1M
```