# Obtain a Unique ID by Group in mutate pipeline

Tags: r, dplyr

Since the new dplyr v1.0.0 update came out I noticed that the function `group_indices()` has the `...` deprecated. I use this function a lot in my work and I like to use it in a `mutate`.

e.g. Using `dplyr v0.8.3` I was able to do something like this very easily:

#Note that I have not run this code as I no longer have v0.8.3 on my machine.

```
library(dplyr) # v0.8.3
rep_data <- data.frame(
  x = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c"),
  y = c("v1", "v1", "v2", "v3", "v1", "v2", "v3", "v3"),
  expect_output = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
)
rep_data %>%
  mutate(expect_output2 = group_indices(x, y))
```

`expect_output2` should give effectively the same results as `expect_output`.

Now that the `...` are deprecated I'd like to move away from using them but I'm unsure of how to do the same thing as above.

I'm basically asking this question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39650511/r-group-by-variable-and-then-assign-a-unique-id) but this question is now outdated with the new `dplyr` version.

When I run the code above using `dplyr v1.0.0` I get the warning message:

```
Warning message:
The `...` argument of `group_keys()` is deprecated as of dplyr 1.0.0.
Please `group_by()` first
```

So I've tried to do the following

```
library(dplyr) # v1.0.0
rep_data %>% 
  group_by(x, y) %>% 
  mutate(expect_output3 = group_indices(.))
```

Which results in an error

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `expect_output3`.
x Input `expect_output3` can't be recycled to size 2.
i Input `expect_output3` is `group_indices(.)`.
i Input `expect_output3` must be size 2 or 1, not 8.
i The error occured in group 1: x = "a", y = "v1".
```

Keeping `group_indices` out of the `mutate` works fine and returns the expected vector however I'd like to keep manipulating my data in a pipe chain and not have to assign it like I've seen on other questions
e.g. I don't want to have to do this

```
rep_data$expect_output3 = rep_data %>% group_by(x,y) %>% group_indices()
```

Is there a way to `group_indices()` and add this vector to my data while maintaining my pipe chain? I'm more than happy to use a different function than `group_indices()` however I haven't quite found one that works for my purposes yet.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I am not getting the error with 1.0.0 `rep_data %>% group_by(x, y) %>% mutate(expect_output2 = group_indices())`

Comment: I get a warning suggesting the approach you noted in your answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error cannot be reproduced in `dplyr 1.0.0`, but the `group_indices` is getting deprecated, instead use `cur_group_id`

```
library(dplyr)# 1.0.0
rep_data %>% 
     group_by(x, y) %>% 
     mutate(expect_output2 =cur_group_id())
# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   x, y [7]
#  x     y     expect_output expect_output2
#  <chr> <chr>         <dbl>          <int>
#1 a     v1                1              1
#2 a     v1                1              1
#3 a     v2                2              2
#4 a     v3                3              3
#5 b     v1                4              4
#6 b     v2                5              5
#7 b     v3                6              6
#8 c     v3                7              7
```